# How to fix PowerBI not installing?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have Windows 10. I have tried two ways to download and install PowerBI SEVERAL times.

1. From the Microsoft Store - The app is downloaded but when I click on it, for just a second the loading icon comes and then nothing. It just doesn't open.
2. From the [Mircosoft download centre](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=bb98f535-0b0d-4f1e-96d2-2b3056e0b9e3). Here, the installer is downloaded. But when I click on it the same thing happens, the loading icon comes for a second and then nothing.

Of course, I have tried running as an administrator as well. I have uninstalled and installed it several times.

Comment: do you have enough space in your disk?

Comment: Yes, there is no space issue.